# String contains correct version of java

Tags: bash

I am new to Bash and having a problem checking a variable contains a string

Works:

```
foo="abc def ghi"

if [[ "$foo" =~ "def" ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

Does not work (issue i'm having):

```
javaVersion="$(java -version)"

if [[ "$javaVersion" =~ "1.8.0_74" ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

I have manually checked the variable contains the string 1.8.0_74.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `java -version` prints the information to `stderr(2)` stream instead of `stdout(1)`. You need to capture both of them as `2>&1` which *literally* means write the standard error output stream *also* to standard output stream.

```
javaVersion="$(java -version 2>&1)"
if [[ "$javaVersion" =~ "1.8.0_74" ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

will work as expected.

Also you don't a a regex operator for this comparison, a simple `glob` comparison using the `test` operator `[[` would suffice,

```
if [[ "$javaVersion" == *"1.8.0_74"* ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```